# How to group Loop by index in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I'm making a notification system (Let me know when you arrive) and I'm having trouble grouping by email. I need to group the products with specific emails to set up email sending.My problem is to separate the separate output by email

Array

```
   $resultado = array(
      array( 'email' => 'de@email.com' , 'ean' => '1278', 'desc' => 'PROD1' ),
      array( 'email' => 'de@email.com' , 'ean' => '2342', 'desc' => 'PROD2' ),
      array( 'email' => 'de@email.com' , 'ean' => '7567', 'desc' => 'PROD3' ),
      array( 'email' => 'ma@email.com' , 'ean' => '5555', 'desc' => 'PROD4' ),
      array( 'email' => 'ma@email.com' , 'ean' => '3335', 'desc' => 'PROD5' ),
 
   );
```

Group

```
   $saida = array();
 
   foreach ($resultado as $res) {
 
      if( !isset( $saida[$res['email']] ) ) {
         $saida[$res['email']] = array();
      }
      array_push( $saida[$res['email']], $res['ean'], $res['desc'], $res['email']);

   }
```

OUT

```
       echo"<pre>";
       print_r( $saida );
       echo"</pre>";   
    
Array

    (
        [de@email.com] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1278
                [1] => PROD1
                [2] => de@email.com
                [3] => 2342
                [4] => PROD2
                [5] => de@email.com
                [6] => 7567
                [7] => PROD3
                [8] => de@email.com
            )
    
        [ma@email.com] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5555
                [1] => PROD4
                [2] => ma@email.com
                [3] => 3335
                [4] => PROD5
                [5] => ma@email.com
            )
    
    )
```

I NEED DISPLAY A BREAK LINE (Only when the email is different)

```
PROD1 - 1278 - de@email.com
PROD2 - 2342 - de@email.com
PROD3 - 7567 - de@email.com
___________________________________

PROD4 - 5555 - ma@email.com
PROD5 - 3335 - ma@email.com
```

And send emails

```
 $return = sendEmail( TO, SITE, '$mails_HERE' , HOST, '[' . SITE . '] ' . $subject, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can first filter out the unique mails and then search the array for corresponding emails data.

```
$resultado = array(
    array( 'email' => 'de@email.com' , 'ean' => '1278', 'desc' => 'PROD1' ),
    array( 'email' => 'de@email.com' , 'ean' => '2342', 'desc' => 'PROD2' ),
    array( 'email' => 'de@email.com' , 'ean' => '7567', 'desc' => 'PROD3' ),
    array( 'email' => 'ma@email.com' , 'ean' => '5555', 'desc' => 'PROD4' ),
    array( 'email' => 'ma@email.com' , 'ean' => '3335', 'desc' => 'PROD5' ),

 );

 
$emails =  array_unique(array_column( $resultado, 'email' ));
$grouped = [];

//looking for each email's corresponding data and saving it in group array
foreach ($emails as $key1 => $each ) {
    foreach ($resultado as $value) {
            if( $value['email'] === $each ){
                unset($value['email']);
                $grouped[$each][] = $value;
            }
    }
}


// printing the group data
foreach ($grouped as $key => $each_member ) {
    foreach ($each_member as $value) {
        echo"<pre>";
        echo  $value['desc'] . ' ' . $value['ean'] . ' ' . $key;
        echo"</pre>"; 
    }
   echo '-------------------------';
}
```

Comment: That way, add the line break at each step, I need to add the break only when the email is different, as in the example above. (I edited the question)

Comment: @denis, i have updated the answer to put the line break position

Answer (score 0):

you just need to group your items.

```
$results = array(
    array( 'email' => 'de@email.com' , 'ean' => '1278', 'desc' => 'PROD1' ),
    array( 'email' => 'de@email.com' , 'ean' => '2342', 'desc' => 'PROD2' ),
    array( 'email' => 'de@email.com' , 'ean' => '7567', 'desc' => 'PROD3' ),
    array( 'email' => 'ma@email.com' , 'ean' => '5555', 'desc' => 'PROD4' ),
    array( 'email' => 'ma@email.com' , 'ean' => '3335', 'desc' => 'PROD5' )
);

$data = [];

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data[$result['email']][] = $result;
}
```

**And that's it.**